# Erroneous behavior when iterating over array with coalesce operation and changing array items by reference

Tags: php

I noticed that iterating over array and modifying items by reference has different behavior depending on whether I use coalesce operation for the array.

Lets's have a simple array:

```
$array = [1,2,3];
```

If I iterate over the array and modify its items by reference:

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
    $item = 4;
}
```

The array values have been changed to 4.

However, in some cases we need to check whether an array actually exists

```
foreach ($array ?? [] as &$item) {
    $item = 4;
}
```

To my surprise, the values have not been changed. Clearly, the array exists and is not empty, which means that the coalesce operator should not make any difference.
Any ideas why?

Comment: The operator actually returns a copy of the operand, not the operand itself. Which kind of makes sense, once you think about the examples in the documentation...

Comment: Why should the array you are looping over not exist? Why not check for that?

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve] that shows what you're writing about? Something anyone can run easily without guessing. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Here is a working MCVE https://3v4l.org/iZdnA Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: @arkascha It does make sense, but is not stated explicitly and I imho the implicit logic should be documented. That's what I assumed as well but wanted to make sure

Comment: @NicoHaase Long story short, I'm using laravel and I'm implementing replacement logic inside a FormRequest. Yes, I could check whether the array exists, however this specific behavior got me curios.

Comment: @Dharman This is exactly what I mean and what I should have provided myself. Thank you for the assistance!